# How to pass the external javascript variable as sql parameter in pentaho?

Tags: javascript, sql, pentaho, pentaho-cde

I used the javascript code as external file for TamilNadu map and used the below SQL code for the table component of pentaho.

Now by clicking on the button, I want to display the table by passing javascript variable as parameter.

javascript code:-

```
var js_city = 'coimbatore';
```

SQL code:

```
SELECT 
     CONCAT(UCASE(LEFT(A, 1)), SUBSTRING(A, 2)) AS 'Service Center Name',
    CONCAT(UCASE(LEFT(B, 1)), SUBSTRING(B, 2)) AS 'State',
     CONCAT(UCASE(LEFT(C, 1)), SUBSTRING(C, 2)) AS 'Status'
       FROM
    (SELECT 
        LOWER(A.service_center_name) AS A,
        A.status AS C,
        LOWER(C.branch_name) AS 'B'
    FROM
        customers A
    INNER JOIN ascs B ON A.serv_cent_mob_no = B.contact_number
    INNER JOIN branches C ON B.branch_id = C.id
    GROUP BY A.service_center_name , A.status , C.branch_name) AS Issue
       WHERE B=${sqlcity};
```

How to pass the "js_city" variable as  "sqlcity" parameter in pentaho ?

Comment: Kindly help us to solve this problem.

Comment: I guess you are making it complex.. Can you explain your requirement.

Comment: Here I used external javascript for a map & using the datasourse panel I connected database and get the table with country details .    Now while clicking on the map, I want to pass the value(country name ) as parameter to sql and want to display the table details .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Say For Example:

1.Initially define the **countryName()** into external js .
2.Simple parameter name is : **cityPara**
3.Go to pentaho cde ->components panel -> script->funtion -> you have to call the external js value & set the parameter value. 
 **function script:**

```
function countryName(){ 
    dashboard.fireChange('${p:cityPara}',js_city);
    console.log("countryName :", js_city);
}
```